# Recovering from a connection failure when reading a large resultset

Tags: java, sql, oracle, database-connection, resultset

I'm sending a query from Java to an Oracle database, and getting the results in a ResultSet:

```
ResultSet rset = null;
try{
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then writing the results to file:

```
while(rset.next()){
    for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++){
        out.append(rset.getString(i) + ";");
    }
    out.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

The ResultSet is large. Gigabytes. Exporting all this data to file takes a while, but that's not the issue. The problem is the connection to the database, which drops away every now and again - while I'm still reading out data. I can have my code reconnect and re-execute the query, and I can read the output file to see how far I've gotten.

My remaining question is: what would be the best way to get to where I was in the ResultSet?

- do the while(rset.next()) until I'm at the right row number?
- surround the original query with a SELECT * FROM (...) WHERE rownum > ...?
- other/better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> My remaining question is: what would be the best way to get to where I was in the ResultSet?

It's difficult to say what the *best* way would be. You need to try one or more approaches and see if you're comfortable with them.

> do the while(rset.next()) until I'm at the right row number?

IMO this is not efficient because if the previous attempt fail at row 1 million, the code will need to skip 1 millions rows before restarting.

> surround the original query with a SELECT * FROM (...) WHERE rownum > ...?

This one is more promising because you can quickly *skip* the already processed rows.
However, you MUST ensure that the order the order of the rows AND the content of the rows remain the same between two attempts.

> other/better suggestions?

What about splitting the results and distribute smaller parts to threads ?

Comment: That indeed is my biggest concern with the rownum option. And forcing the data to be ordered before applying the rownum would cause the database to go over the entire dataset before starting to return it -> probably make the whole thing very slow.

Comment: I think the bottleneck for the speed is the bandwidth I'm allotted, so multithreading wouldn't reduce the amount of time needed for the connection to be open. But maybe I'm missing your point?